# Movie in which aliens disguise one of them as a cartoon chicken, mistakingly thinking it will help him blend on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, space

I want to find a film I watched as a child. I hope someone can help me with this.

The plot is rather weird. First, there were some aliens, who wanted to send one of them to Earth. They wanted to disguise him as an ordinary Earth creature, but they had no idea what life on Earth looks like, so they used some device which was supposed to show them local life forms. However, this device showed them a TV show with a cartoon chicken, so the aliens decided that the life on Earth is two-dimensional and disguised that guy as the chicken from the show.

The aliens also had an orb which could read minds and control people's behaviour (or something like that). So the chicken-like alien guy took this thing with him and lost it on Earth. Then it was found by a schoolboy, who later started using the orb on other people.

Also, there was an old rock musician who had experienced an alien encounter before.

No, it wasn't animation. It was a film, but the main character was animated.

BTW, I drew what the orb looked like:

[image: blue and silver orb]

UPD: Thank you for the answer! It really looks like **King of the Farm**. Unfortunately, I can't tick the answer because of the mess with my accounts. But still thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Was it animation?

Comment: Perhaps the most important question: when did you watch that? When would it have been made?

Comment: An alien disguised itself as a chicken? That makes perfect sense. Chickens are the most populous bird species on the planet. They must be an evolutionary success to be so many. **They got that way by being small, flightless, and tasty.** Why else would the dominant species breed so many?

Comment: Good drawing @olga

Comment: @olga2019: Did the instructions provided to merge accounts not work for you?

Answer (score 12):

This is the 2002 film, *[King of the Farm](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0328327/)*, originally titled *El Rey de la Granja*.

[image: Movie poster for King of the Farm]

> In a distant galaxy, Neuronia controls the minds of the inhabitants until one of them escapes with the sphere.

A longer review can be found [here](https://m.chicagoreader.com/chicago/the-king-of-the-farm/Film?oid=1066523).

> A fairly engaging children's film that mixes live action with computer and conventional animation. On a distant asteroid a young hero steals a powerful sphere from an evil tyrant and his robot henchman. He ends up stranded on earth disguised, due to his misinterpretation of intercepted TV signals, as an animated chicken from a cartoon show. The sphere falls into the hands of some kids at a summer camp, with shambolic results. The gentle humor focuses on the stupidity of grown-ups and the joy of food fights. Adults may find this a bit wearing, but young kids will like it. In Spanish with subtitles.

You can see one of the mind control scenes here:

I found the original film clip with a search query of `film aliens "cartoon chicken" disguise -disney` on Google (glad I clicked into it), and someone identified the film in the comments. Unfortunately, that clip is no longer available, and the official trailer only has the CG-based intro, although the sphere can be briefly seen in the trailer.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.